# `heroku-cli: Installing core plugins` Stalling For Every Command

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, heroku-toolbelt, browserify-rails

About a week ago Heroku was working perfectly. Without trying any other commands, I ran `heroku buildpacks:set https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-multi.git` from this [repo](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-multi) since it was recommended by a [react_rails+browserify_rails](http://blog.arkency.com/2015/04/bring-commonjs-to-your-asset-pipeline/) tutorial I was using as reference.

Now, every command calls for Heroku to install core plugins and, then, gets stuck installing core plugins indefinitely.

Example(s):
`heroku -h` or `heroku --version` or `heroku login` gives:

```
heroku-cli: Installing core plugins...
```

I am running a Mac Mavericks 10.9.5.

I have uninstalled (following the their guide online), using both homebrew and terminal commands. Then reinstalled using their standalone download and brew. I have also restarted my laptop.

Due to the error-less, non-terminating state of the issue, I am at a loss for ideas and would appreciate all the help.

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced the same issue. Run the following command:

```
HEROKU_DEBUG=1 heroku login
```

If it hangs, kill it then retry a few times.

Answer (score 0):

```
HEROKU_DEBUG=1
```

helps to see the trace and sets some flags so using it on all commands is fine.

deleting `~/.heroku/`
then installing the plugins explicitly worked.

```
heroku plugins:install
```